Why Shouldn't React Components Be Declared as Async Functions in Client-Side Rendering?
I'm building a React application using client-side rendering and came across a situation where I need to fetch data inside a component. I'm tempted to declare my React component as an async function so that I can use await to handle the asynchronous operations directly. However, I've read in several places that it's not a good practice to do this.
Could someone help explain why I shouldn't declare a React component as an async function? What are the potential pitfalls of doing so, and what are the best practices for handling asynchronous code in React components?
Any examples or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!

React components render something on the screen so React expects the components to return JSX(or null). React considers this operation to be synchronous and works accordingly. So if you declare a component as an async function, it will return a promise and react doesn't know how to handle that promise. So even if the app doesn't crash, it will introduce inconsistencies.
Now fetching data inside a react component isn't uncommon and one common practice is to do this by using the "useEffect" hook. I won't go into detail in explaining hooks or how to use "useEffect" hook as it will make the post unnecessarily lengthy. These are fundamental concepts in React and you can find many resources online. Here are a few links to get you started:
UseEffect Documentation
React Hooks – How to Use the useState & useEffect Hooks in Your Project
Using Async funtions in UseEffect()
